# C++ Unexpected number output

Tags: c++, class, output

EDIT: Fixed the problem thanks to advice from below. Changed the return type of evaluation() from an int to a void.

I'm learning how to use classes, and I'm experiencing a problem. I keep getting an output that says:

```
0
They are not equal.
4469696
```

Where is that last number coming from? It should be somewhere after
the line

```
std::cout << Thing.evaluation(Thing.getValue()) << std::endl;
```

but I don't see anything that could possibly be outputting that value. Is it memory leakage?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

class classTest
{
      public:
             int equivalency(int x, int y)
             {
                 if (x == y)
                 {
                       value = 1;
                 } else
                 {
                       value = 0;      
                 }
             }

             int evaluation(int z)
             {
                 if (z == 0)
                 {
                       std::cout << "They are not equal." << std::endl;
                 } else 
                  {
                        std::cout << "They are equal." << std::endl;
                  }
             }

             int getValue()
             {
                 return value;
             }

       private:
              int value;
};

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    classTest Thing;

    std::cout << "Enter two numbers for comparison." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a >> b;

    Thing.equivalency(a, b);

    std::cout << Thing.getValue() << std::endl;

    std::cout << Thing.evaluation(Thing.getValue()) << std::endl;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `classTest::evaluation()` never assigns a return value, and if your compiler warnings were configured remotely well, it would inform you of this (and likely is).

Comment: Turn up your warning level.

Comment: `equivalency()` has the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `evaluation()` you print the expected messages. Then you don't return anything from this function although it is declared to return `int`, i.e., you get undefined behavior. Further more, you actually point the random result since you output the result of the call:

```
std::cout << Thing.evaluation(Thing.getValue()) << std::endl;
```

BTW, don't use `std::endl`! If you want a newline, use `'\n'`, if you want to flush the buffer use `std::flush`. Unnecessary use of `std::endl` is a relatively frequent source of major performance problems.

Comment: Beat me to it. +1 for the bonus advice on using std::endl (didn't know that and I plead guilty to its overuse).

Comment: I changed the return type of evaluation() from an int to a void. It fixed the problem. Thanks for the advice! I'll be sure to use std::flush and "\n" from now on.

Comment: @BrandonHoutzer: This is not the solution to your problem. If evaluation() outputs information and does not return a value you should not be outputting the result of the function in the first place. I'm quite surprised that it's even allowed to output the return value of a void function.

Comment: @Alexandre P. Levasseur: It doesn't return anything. It prints to the command prompt.

Comment: @BrandonHoutzer: What Alexandre means is: `std::cout << f();` shouldn't compile if the function is declared as `void f()`. I'm assuming you replace the output/call in `main()` by a simple statement: `Thing.evaluation(Thing.getvalue());`

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Oh. I did change that so that it was just calling the function instead of using std::cout.